# Installing windows 8.1 on drive letter A [SSD]?

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd

I want to install windows 8.1 on my computer SSD and before I waste my time searching all over the install how to change the drive letter for the system partition, I would like to know if it's even possible. Back in the days with windows XP even though we didn't have a floppy drive, the floppy drive letter A: was taken (by a floppy drive icon). I am using windows 8 now and I don't remember if the drive letter could be chosen during the installation. But inside windows 8 I can change the letter of non system drives and I can also change it to A: or B:. That's why I am wondering. There are so few Letters in the alphabet (my current config uses almost all of them) and I want my System drive to be the first drive in the "My computer" "directory"

Comment: A & B are reserved for floppy drives, legacy, whether you have them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think windows by default marks your system partition as C:, so if you install another windows on another drive and boot from it, you will see your windows partition as C. If you happen to have another system drive (e.g. your current windows drive as C), I think it will appear as D or the first available letter in the new installation.

Comment: OK I get it and I also get that's what you think (the first available letters would be A or B but those letter are never use unless manually chosen through the manager). another thing is that once I installed two XP (different partitions) and the second installed XP took the letter D even when I boot from it. So I wander if I install the same OS on as many partition as possible (24+) will the 25th install give me the A drive (if in fact XP behaved that way because the other drive was XP too)

Comment: Honestly I am not sure if this hypothetical situation is ever going to happen for someone. Please go ahead and mark my response as answer and vote it up.